# how to remove text box value on check box unchecked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Hi i have two check boxes  PlanA AND AndroidApps and one textbox when i checked check box then text box enable  and when i unchecked thrn text dox disabled but problem is when tex box is enable and i write something in text box and then unchecked my checkbox then my textbox disabled but that text which i typed it does not delete and text box does not clear

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main_box').on('change',function(e) {
        console.log("dfsd");
       $("#a2").prop("checked",this.checked);
     $("#emailid").prop("disabled", !$(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

                <input id="main_box"type="checkbox" name="PlanA" value="A"><label for="PlanA"><span style="font-weight:bold">PlanA</span></label><br>
                <input name="PlanA" type="hidden" value=0 />


                <input type="checkbox" name="AndroidApps" id="a2" value=1><label for="AndroidApps"><span style="font-weight:bold">AndroidApps</span></label><br>
                <input name="AndroidApps" type="hidden" value=0 />


                         <input type="text" name="emailid"id="emailid"disabled="disabled" required size="45"  >

</body>
</html>
```

How can i achieve this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** to set the value of your `input`:

```
$("#emailid").val('');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qb3k6/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add a condition

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main_box').on('change', function (e) {
        $("#a2").prop("checked", this.checked);
        $("#emailid").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
        if(!this.checked){
            $("#emailid").val('');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nRcU7/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use val() to set the value of your input:

```
$("#emailid").val('');
```

and if your are retrieving values, you use:

```
$(selector).val()
```

Don't get confused with those two

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Use this Link::
http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/DM9b9/

contains code for checkbox check ::

```
$("#chk").click(function(){
     if($("#chk").is(":checked"))
     {
        $("#txt").val('');
     }
})
```